# Weblogic 12.2.1.4 - java.sql.SQLException / CLOB Compatibility Issue

Tags: java, weblogic12c

After upgrading to Weblogic 12.2.1.4, we're seeing that certain functions (for example length() and getCharacterStream()) that read CLOB data are throwing java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed errors. Is there some kind of compatibility issue with WL 12.2.1.4? Is there an alternative way of processing CLOBs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved this error by changing the settings in Weblogic connection pool used .
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/jdbc/jdbc_datasources/DisableWrapping.html
Advanced setting :
In Wrap Data Types, deselect the checkbox todisable wrapping

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Had exactly the same problem after a migration to Weblogic 12.2.1.4. Disabling the "Wrap Data Types" option solved the problem. A restart of the Weblogic server was necessary, juste resetting the data source was not enough.

Answer (score 1):

It's an oracle Bug. However **oracle** say that is correct behavior to close the connection.

Work around is to **disable** `"wrap data type"` option in data source advance **settings**.

Fix : Change the app so reading and absorbing LOB is completed within a single transaction.